# Volley array request проблемы при использовании в fragment

Tags: java, json, recyclerview, android-volley

Доброго времени суток.

Хочу получить результат обращения к api сайта.
Вот фрагмент в котором я это хочу сделать.
заполнения cardView попросту не происходит.
permissions для доступа в интернет включены.
возможно я не правильно написал метод makeRequestCapCoin, прошу помочь с решением
Вот пример

```html
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "bitcoin",
      "rank": "1",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "supply": "17193925.0000000000000000",
      "maxSupply": "21000000.0000000000000000",
      "marketCapUsd": "119150835874.4699281625807300",
      "volumeUsd24Hr": "2927959461.1750323310959460",
      "priceUsd": "6929.8217756835584756",
      "changePercent24Hr": "-0.8101417214350335",
      "vwap24Hr": "7175.0663247679233209"
    },
    {
      "id": "ethereum",
      "rank": "2",
      "symbol": "ETH",
      "name": "Ethereum",
      "supply": "101160540.0000000000000000",
      "maxSupply": null,
      "marketCapUsd": "40967739219.6612727047843840",
      "volumeUsd24Hr": "1026669440.6451482672850841",
      "priceUsd": "404.9774667045200896",
      "changePercent24Hr": "-0.0999626159535347",
      "vwap24Hr": "415.3288028454417241"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> cRank = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> cName = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> cSymbol = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> cPrice = new ArrayList<>();
public FragmentTwo() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    makeRequestCapCoin();

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mContext, cRank, cName, cSymbol, cPrice);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    return root;
}

private void makeRequestCapCoin() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    String jsonUrl = "https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets?limit=5";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, jsonUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i > jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    cRank.add(object.getString("rank"));
                    cName.add(object.getString("name"));
                    cSymbol.add(object.getString("symbol"));
                    cPrice.add(object.getString("priceUsd"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
  }
}
```

Адаптер

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<String> cRank;
ArrayList<String> cName;
ArrayList<String> cSymbol;
ArrayList<String> cPrice;

private Context context;



public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> cRank, ArrayList<String> cName, ArrayList<String> cSymbol, ArrayList<String> cPrice) {
    this.context=context;
    this.cRank = cRank;
    this.cName = cName;
    this.cSymbol = cSymbol;
    this.cPrice = cPrice;

}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // infalte the item Layout
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_top, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v); // pass the view to View Holder
    return vh;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // set the data in items
    holder.cRank.setText(cRank.get(position));
    holder.cName.setText(cName.get(position));
    holder.cSymbol.setText(cSymbol.get(position));
    holder.cPrice.setText(cPrice.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cRank.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView cRank, cName, cSymbol, cPrice;// init the item view's
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        // get the reference of item view's
        cRank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cryptoRank);
        cName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cryptoName);
        cSymbol = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cryptoSymbol);
        cPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cryptoPrice);

    }
  }
}
```

fragment_two.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#D81B60"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

item_top.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#039BE5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_whatshot" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cryptoRank"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cryptoName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cryptoRank"
            android:text="Bitcoin"
            android:textColor="#8BC34A"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cryptoSymbol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cryptoName"
            android:text="BTC"
            android:textColor="#FFEB3B"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/containerInfo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Цена в USD: "
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cryptoPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/price"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:text="4645.63874"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

dependency

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Кажется, вы просто забыли уведомить адаптер об обновлении данных. Попробуйте добавить `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` в `onResponse` после цикла.

Comment: спасибо), действительно помогло. немного переписал код. все что находилось в моем методе перенес в onCreateView.
изменил немного структуру json и метод onResponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Кажется, вы просто забыли уведомить адаптер об обновлении данных. Попробуйте добавить adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() в onResponse после цикла. – ЮрийСПб

Все изменения в коде отмечены комментариями

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
private Context mContext;

private ArrayList<String> cRank = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> cName = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> cSymbol = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> cPrice = new ArrayList<>();

public FragmentTwo() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    final CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext(), cRank, cName, cSymbol, cPrice);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    // JsonArrayRequest modified !!! The previous method "makeRequestCapCoin()" has been deleted.
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    String jsonUrl = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/15rrou";
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            jsonUrl,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            System.out.println(jsonObject);
                            cRank.add(jsonObject.getString("market_cap_rank"));
                            cName.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                            cSymbol.add(jsonObject.getString("symbol"));
                            cPrice.add(jsonObject.getString("current_price"));
                        }
                        // Added notify for Adapter
                        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    return root;
  }
}
```